# Testing principal component analysis residuals between groups

Tags: pca, chemometrics

I have built a calibration model using principal component regression relating PCs extracted from multivariate spectra to their calibration factors. We are trying to determine if our calibration model will apply to spectra collected under a different condition.

How would we determine if the PCs selected from the training set explain the same amount of variance in the unknown data set? I'm aware of Jackson & Mudholkars Q and Q-alpha, but I am not certain they are the best way to answer this question. My intuition is to subject the absolute Q values to a 1-way ANOVA similar to Levene's Test for homogeneity of variance. Unfortunately, while Q values are residuals, they are not residuals from a group mean which is where Levene's test is typically used.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: this is a non-answer, questioning your question.

> determine if our calibration model will apply to spectra collected under a different condition.

This sounds like a perfectly sensible task to me and for a predictive model such as PCR I'd formulate this applicability as robustness or ruggedness of the predictions wrt. the condition in question. (There may be reasons not to focus on predictions, if that's the case for your question, please explain this in more detail)

But I don't see how

> determine if the PCs selected from the training set explain the same amount of variance in the unknown data set

(i.e. showing Q is unaffected by the change)

would answer the first question!?

There may be situations where question 2 same amount of explained variance is a sensible surrogate for question 1, but IMHO they would be exceedingly rare special cases. One prerequisite would be that you *know* the level of noise does *not* change when changing acquisition conditions.

It is also possible to construct situations where your method is robust/rugged wrt. the changing condition and there is no change in the PCA projection residuals. But the reverse is not true!

- Unchanged Q **does not** imply any kind of robustness/ruggedness
- Change in Q **does not** imply lack of  robustness/ruggedness
- Change in Q **is not sufficient** to show robustness/ruggedness

---

In general, I'd say:

- Assuming your (possibly pre-processed) spectra are affected by the condition (otherwise: show that the spectra are unaffected),
- you *want* these changes to end up in the PCR residuals (either Q or the ILS residuals) - otherwise your method cannot be robust/rugged wrt. this particular condition.